# Extract URL stream from webpage?

Tags: http, url, video-streaming, html5-video, rtsp

I am trying to extract direct HTTP, RTSP, MP stream URLs or something that I can work with from this website:
http://kamery.ovanet.cz/
Any idea how to do it, I've tried f12 using chrome, but wasn't sucessful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

> *"Any idea how to do it, I've tried `F12` using Chrome, but wasn't successful."*

You have to first open the `Network` tab of Chrome's Developer tools then...

1. In the small text box that shows `filter` text, type in there: `.m3u8`
2. Select a camera. It should show multiple `.m3u8` files being loaded
3. Choose a `playlist.m3u8` that does not have `?auth=b64%3A` etc in the URL

Try testing this link (is M3U8 playlist) : 
https://stream.ovanet.cz/ovanet/f89ab1fdfeba19d51fa26dd491edcbaa/camera97/playlist.m3u8

You can try the above link with some online player : [HLS Stream Tester](https://videojs.github.io/videojs-contrib-hls/).

**Edit : Regarding comments...**

> *"The URL link works for just a while and then it stops. Can I solve it somehow?"*

Yes, their links are time-limited and will expire so you need a **page refresh** to get the newest version of the M3U8 link.

If you want to automate the process then you will have to write code that achieves the following:

1. Choose a camera ID **number** from [this listing](http://kamery.ovanet.cz/function/seznam_krizovatek.php). Notice that the `"cam_id"` is followed by the related **location**'s `"title"`. Example is `"cam_id":19`.
2. Using the camera's ID number, make a request to this URL:

https://stream.ovanet.cz/player/api/embed-live.js?stream=camera19&_=XXXX

*Note:* Where `XXXX` is the [current time as a UNIX timestamp](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/) (eg : `1659717867824`).

3. This will return some text. Part of **that text has the URL with the  Base64** "auth" that you need for a **correct** request. You get it by finding the start position of `return "` and extracting (via **String** functions) everything between up until the first occurrence of `";` going forward from the start position.
4. Request this newly extracted link, which looks like example:

https://stream.ovanet.cz/ovanet/camera19/playlist.m3u8?auth=b64%3AY2FtZXJhMTk6OjoxMjg0MzQzMTU3OjE2NTk3MjE1NjAwODc6MTY1OTcyNTE2MDo5Mi40MC4xOTAuMjc6MDdiZGUxN2MwMGY1Nzg5YTkwZjlkMmY3YjdmM2JmYTM%3D

5. There will be **a re-direct to another URL** of same M3U8 file name but from a different location, so you need to find out this new URL. It has the **folder name** you need.

Eg: the folder name is: `/f3630f4527ce8ddd69bf27580737d66f/` from: 
 https://stream.ovanet.cz/ovanet/f3630f4527ce8ddd69bf27580737d66f/camera19/playlist.m3u8

The final URL is basically (using `chunklist.m3u8` seems to work better):

https://stream.ovanet.cz/ovanet/f3630f4527ce8ddd69bf27580737d66f/camera19/chunklist.m3u8

Comment: Thank you, Although the URL link work for just a while and then it stops. - the same with yours. Can I solve it somehow.?